# Express content of page is always visible even on refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to learn Express and I am trying to build something kinda like bit.ly's web page (The url shortener and stuff) Right now I can get the links to be displayed on page and everything but when I refresh the page the link is still there, it doesn't disappear until I restart the server; I can generate new links and it's replaced but if I refresh the page it doesn't go away.

Express:

```
var data;
var url;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    //var d_20803340c40722494a7c737b0725d0178d4e1d40;
    res.render('index', { 'data': data, 'link': url });
});

/* POST HANDLER */
router.post('/link', function(req, res, next) {
    var pattern = /^((http|https|):\/\/)/;
    url = req.body.link;

    if (!pattern.test(url))
    {
        url = "http://" + url;
        bitly.shorten(url)
        .then(response => {
            data = response.data.url;

            res.redirect('/');
        });
    }
})
```

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var data;` and `var url;` are in a global scope, outside of the `get` function. This means that during the post to `'/link'` when you set `url` and `data` they are set at a global scope that is in your program, and outside of any individual request. Because you're then sending these values into the `res.render`, once they are set they are going to be given to the client on every get request.

The reason you're seeing it on refresh is because the program has these stored outside of the scope of an individual request, and when you refresh (Doing a new GET request and rendering) you're going to get the same values every time.

Comment: Ah I see, so, what could be a fix for this so I can still pass the variables to the templating engine and change the value of these with the information of the post request?

Comment: @bexo Lots of ways, depending on what you want to do. First thing that comes to mind is that you could redirect to `'/?data=...&link=...'` and have the `get` route only send those down if it finds them in the query string. Then include a home link that would redirect to the page with no query string. Another answer (which I like much better) would be to make the `post` return a JSON object with the data instead of doing a redirect. Then do the POST async from the client and display the data.